# how to add contents in an array in unit test

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following statement

```
    let(:parsed_response) { JSON.parse(response.body) }
```

It returns me following output

```
{"a"=>1, "b"=>"2", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"4", "e"=>"5", "f"=>[]}
```

and i have following statement

```
  let(:f_output) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:something,
                       g: something.id,
                       h: something2.id,
                       i: 'something')
  end
```

How can i load f element from first statement output with the result from f_output object?

```
{"a"=>1, "b"=>"abc", "c"=>"def", "d"=>"ges", "e"=>"ehd", "f"=>["g"=>"kjl", "h"=>"oel", "i"=>"pde"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge in the attributes:

```
parsed_response.merge('f' => f_output.attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).

So if you wanted it to always be a part of your **parsed_response**, you can change your `let` statement to something like:

```
let(:parsed_response) { JSON.parse(response.body).merge('f' => f_output.attribtutes) }
```